# Pull values from SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, arrays, api, simplexml, namecheap

I'm using the namecheap API to do some stuff, it's the first time I've used a API and I'm running into a bit of a problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
$ApiKey = "**********************";
$ApiUser = "*****";
$UserName = "*********";
$ClientIP = "********";
$NamecheapURI = "https://api.namecheap.com/xml.response";

$executionURL = $NamecheapURI."?ApiUser=".$ApiUser."&ApiKey=".$ApiKey."&UserName=".$UserName."&Command=namecheap.domains.check&ClientIp=".$ClientIP."&DomainList=".$domain;

$xml = simplexml_load_file($executionURL);

print_r($xml);
```

When print $xml I am returned simple XML objects:

```
  SimpleXMLElement Object
  (
  [@attributes] =&gt; Array
    (
        [Status] =&gt; OK
    )

  [Errors] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

  [Warnings] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

  [RequestedCommand] =&gt; namecheap.domains.check
  [CommandResponse] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] =&gt; Array
            (
                [Type] =&gt; namecheap.domains.check
            )

        [DomainCheckResult] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [Domain] =&gt; facebook.com
                        [Available] =&gt; false
                        [ErrorNo] =&gt; 0
                        [Description] =&gt; 
                        [IsPremiumName] =&gt; false
                        [PremiumRegistrationPrice] =&gt; 0
                        [PremiumRenewalPrice] =&gt; 0
                        [PremiumRestorePrice] =&gt; 0
                        [PremiumTransferPrice] =&gt; 0
                        [IcannFee] =&gt; 0
                        [EapFee] =&gt; 0
                    )

            )

    )

  [Server] =&gt; PHX01APIEXT03
  [GMTTimeDifference] =&gt; --5:00
  [ExecutionTime] =&gt; 0.008
)
```

My question is beyond this, how do I move forward and pull data from this?

I've tried treating this as an array but I am getting nowhere, when using is_array() to test if it was an array it says it's not which I don't understand...

I apologise if this is a noob question, I am a bit new to this. In short, what do I need to do to pull data from this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best start for PHP is the official manual. In this case, have a look at [the SimpleXML Basic Examples page](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). The "Array" in the output is just the slightly awkward way `print_r` outputs nested objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning to use SimpleXML is much better than trying to convert it to arrays/json/anything else and simple (hence the name).  A quick example...

```
$response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CommandResponse Type="namecheap.domains.check">
    <DomainCheckResult Domain="facebook.com">
        <Element>1234</Element>
        <Element>12345</Element>
    </DomainCheckResult>
</CommandResponse>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

echo "DOmain=".$xml->DomainCheckResult['Domain'].PHP_EOL;
foreach ( $xml->DomainCheckResult->Element as $value)   {
    echo "Value=".(string)$value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

outputs...

```
DOmain=facebook.com
Value=1234
Value=12345
```

You have to adapt this to your own XML, but the idea is that if you want to access an element of an item you use object notation `->` and if you need to get an attribute, use array notation `[]`.

So in the above code, the first echo (`$xml->DomainCheckResult['Domain']`) gets the `<DomainCheckResult>` element and outputs the Domain attribute.

Then the `foreach` loop says fetch each `<Element>` within `<DomainCheckResult>` and output the value.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, very simple and makes perfect sense and most of all, worked!